# О(,) память сердца! Ты сильней рассудка памяти печальной

Tags: частица, междометие

***О память сердца! Ты сильней

Рассудка памяти печальной.***

У Батюшкова запятой после "О", насколько могу судить, нет. Так и в академических изданиях. 
Тем не менее в современных вариантах  (неавторитетеных) она часто проскакивает.

Хотелось бы понять, почему её нет у автора и почему так хочется её поставить с точки зрения современных представлений.

*Я знаю, что вопрос упирается в то, чем считать О - междометием или частицей. Но тогда, при Батюшкове, правила пунктуации были несколько другими, теория частиц вообще стала более или менее связной не ранее середины двадцатого века, до того отличить частицу от междометия в подобных примерах вообще было проблемно.*

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, никакой особенно разработанной теории здесь и не надо. Если **О** относится к обращению, это точно частица — она усиливает обращение, запятая не нужна; если ко всему предложению, это междометие, запятая нужна. Чтобы определить это, нужно убрать междометие, не являющееся членом предложения; если предложение имеет смысл, это междометие, после него можно поставить даже восклицательный знак, если нет, это частица, относящаяся к обращению.

*О! Ты сильней

Рассудка памяти печальной.*

Появляется чрезмерная экзальтированность, **о** = **ах**, а ахать от того, что память сердца сильнее памяти рассудка, как-то нелогично, чему тут восторгаться?
Следовательно, **О** относится к обращению, а вот чуть усилить, возвысить отношение к памяти сердца нормально, придаёт торжественность.

То же самое и здесь:
*О сердце, сколько ты любило! О разум, сколько ты пылал!* (А. Блок);
*О сеятель благополучный! Сторицею воздаст она твоим трудам* (А. Пушкин).

Сравним:
*О, господа, прекратите ругаться! О (ах), прекратите ругаться! ;

О, дорогой, так грустно, что закончилось лето! О (ах), так грустно, что закончилось лето!*
В данном случае вместо запятой может стоять и восклицательный знак:
*О! Павел Иванович, позвольте мне быть откровенным* (Н. Гоголь).
Как сказала *Jasmin*, здесь пауза при чтении.

Частицы **а** и **да**, стоящие перед повторяющимся обращением, запятой от него не отделяются, а перед ними запятая ставится: *Жмаченко, а Жмаченко, чего ты в своей жизни не жалеешь?* (К. Симонов). *Петька, да Петька же, куда ты запропастился?*
При неповторяющемся обращении **а** выступает в роли междометия и отделяется запятой:
*За что ж ты любишь, а, земляк, березы да снега*? (К. Симонов).

Comment: Все четко и ясно, как в математике!

Comment: А мне вот эта информация кажется вполне ясной, так как допускает авторское решение.  О том, что надо убирать частицу/междометие для проверки ничего не говорится (не очень понятный прием, я о нем не слышала раньше) https://lektsii.org/14-2323.html  1. Частица пред обращением не обособляется (эмоциональное обращение):О мой милый сад! О любимые сердцем обманы! Барин, а барин!Ах Надя, Наденька! Ах витязь! То была Наина!

Comment: 2. Междометие перед обращением выражает чувство, произносится с паузой и обособляется: О, моя утраченная свежесть! О, память сердца! Ты сильней рассудка памяти печальной. Ах, душа моя! Ах, поля мои, борозды милые! Хороши вы в печали своей! Да и вообще, как мне кажется, можно найти множество примеров, где  можно считать слово как междометием, так и частицей. Между этими вариантами нет принципиальной разницы, но есть оттенки смысла, которые выражает именно автор.

Comment: А это ПАС: Частицы о, ах, а и другие, стоящие перед обращениями, от них не отделяются: О мой милый, мой нежный, прекрасный сад (Ч.);  § 103. Если же перед обращением оказывается междометие, то оно отделяется запятой или восклицательным знаком: Ах, поля мои, борозды милые, хороши вы в печали своей (Еc); В качестве междометия может выступать и СЛОВО О (В ЗНАЧЕНИИ АХ): О, моя утраченная свежесть, буйство глаз и половодье чувств (Ее). Вот такая "математика" у Лопатина, тоже с подстановкой.

Comment: *По-моему, никакой особенно разработанной теории здесь и не надо.* - ну как же "не надо", если вы на основании этой теории и делаете свои выводы?! Моя реплика относилась к тому, что вряд ли Батюшков владел всеми этими тонкостями просто в силу того, что их еще не было придумано. Другое дело, что автограф и без того изобилует неточностями и описками (три или четыре на 16 строф) и уверять, что Батюшков вообще сверялся с правилами вряд ли можно...

Comment: В целом я даже не знаю, что сказать. Вы пересказали известное в общем-то наставление о разграничении междометия и частицы, но на вопрос не очень-то ответили. Ваша уверенность строится единственно на какой-то невозможной-де "экзальтированности", но я совсем не уверен, что Батюшков мог рассуждать так или интуитивно предполагать подобное.

Comment: *ахать от того, что память сердца сильнее памяти рассудка, как-то нелогично, чему тут восторгаться?* вот тут я совсем не согласен. Батюшков, видимо, тоже. Память сердца - это не простой эпитет, не финура речи, за ним стоит нечто большее... http://feb-web.ru/feb/batyush/texts/bop/bop-1762.htm?cmd=p  Но это мы уже от вопроса далеко ушли. Достаточно того, что, как сказал, многие сегодня понимают это О именно как междометие, кпорно вставляя запятую. Вот что их сподаигает на такое - вот это мне хотелось бы понять...

Comment: Память сердца - это не простой эпитет, не фигура речи, за ним стоит нечто большее...   Так ведь и я о том:" О относится к обращению", "чуть усилить, возвысить отношение к памяти сердца -  нормально, придаёт торжественность", а усиливать волнение от " ты сильнее этого" - экзальтация. Волнение возникает от слова память сердца, к нему и относится, а в конце предложения стоит точка, там факт, а современные критики, издатели и пр. этого не видят и извращают содержание. Если б это было междометие = ах, в конце был бы восклицательный знак.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что здесь запятая не нужна, это эмоциональное обращение (с частицей О и без паузы).

Прочтение с паузой (с междометием О, выражающим отдельное чувство) менее удачно, так как логическое ударение желательно перенести именно на обращение.

Хотя раньше не было четко разработанной теории частиц и междометий, тем не менее связь паузы и запятой и тогда была вполне понятна.

В любом случае, здесь должно сохраняться авторское решение.